# Get my Twitter ID with twitter4j

Tags: twitter4j

What's the best way to get my own twitter ID from twitter4j?

Say I have the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
  {
  Twitter t; 
  long cursor = -1;
  long myID = 123456789L;
  long[] friendIDs 

  try
    {
    t = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    friendIDs = t.getFollowersIDs(myID, cursor).getIDs();
    //do something with frienIDs ....
   }
```

How to I get the twitter object to generate myID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet it seems you are trying to login to your Twitter A/c and fetch your connections/followers and do something with them.

First you need to register your app with Twitter and generate OAuth Authentication.
You will get following - consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken and accesstokensecret.

Using the keys and secret you would create a Twitter instance, which you can use to access your Twitter User ID.

```
String consumerkey = "consumerkey";
String consumersecret = "consumersecret";
String accesstoken = "accesstoken";
String accesstokensecret = "accesstokensecret";

ConfigurationBuilder twitterConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
twitterConfigBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
twitterConfigBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey);
twitterConfigBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret);
twitterConfigBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken);
twitterConfigBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesstokensecret);

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(twitterConfigBuilder.build()).getInstance();
myID = twitter.getID(); // This will give the id with which application was registered.
```

Hope this helps.
Also check this - http://iag.me/socialmedia/how-to-create-a-twitter-app-in-8-easy-steps/.